# how to scale up the login prompt in UbuntuGNOME 17.04

Tags: display-resolution, ubuntu-gnome, 17.04, gnome-tweak-tool

I am running UbuntuGNOME 17.04 on a laptop with hi-res display (3840x2160).

I am using 2x window scaling in the Tweak Tool.

Everything works perfectly except the login prompt doesn't scale up.  Interestingly, the locked login screen scales fine.  So it's only the before-I-login prompt that isn't scaling.

How do I change global settings to correct this before my profile/preferences have been loaded?

Comment: Very good question :)

Comment: Not implemented in 17.04, read here & following posts to workaround if desired - https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359085&p=13637591&viewfull=1#post13637591